# Mantain the original value in a recursive function c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to solve a square root in a recursive way. I do not want the code to solve that! I am almost done, but I do not know how to mantain the original value of the function:

```
float raizCuadrada(float num, float err) {

    float nuevo = num / 2;
    float resta=(nuevo*nuevo)-num;


    if(resta>err){
        return (raizCuadrada(nuevo, err));
    }
    else if (resta <= err) {
        return (nuevo);
    }
}
```

I basicly want to know how to "save" that first "num" call, somewhere, to use it ALWAYS in the "resta", the "- num" should be always the number that 1st put.

NOTES: I cannot input more inputs. I can only input 1 number and the error.

Comment: Make an overload that takes 3 parameters. The last parameter is the original num. The function with 2 parameters simply calls the one with 3 and the function with 3 parameters does all the work.

Comment: Are you sure about this algorithm? I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a global variable at the top of your code.

```
float num_fixed;

float raizCuadrada(float num, float err) {

    float nuevo = num / 2;
    float resta=(nuevo*nuevo)-num_fixed;

    if(resta>err){
        return (raizCuadrada(nuevo, err));
    }
    else {
        return (nuevo);
    }   
}

int main(void){
  float num = 2.0;
  float err = 0.000001;
  float output;
  num_fixed = num;
  output = raizCuadrada(num, err);
}
```

Comment: 'num_fixed' needs an initialization before it is used.

Comment: Yep, that would be done in the main function and set to the initial value of num. I have updated my answer to show a basic main function. I've also replaced the else if with an else.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the two solutions that have been proposed. Either overload a function that takes three arguments or use a global.

If you for some reason don't want to do that, you can use some trickery:

```
float raizCuadrada(float num, float err) {
   static float org = -1;
   if(org<0)
      org = num;
   float nuevo = num / 2;
   float resta=(nuevo*nuevo)-org;
   float ret;
    if(resta>err)
        ret = raizCuadrada(nuevo, err);
    else 
        ret = nuevo;
    if(org>=0)
       org=-1;
    return ret;
}
```

I would not recommend this method unless you really have a special need for it. It is quite easy to do mistakes, and I cannot think of any real benefit. But since it is possible, I wanted to show it.

Comment: `c++` tag and `malloc` in your code gives you a down vote from me.

Comment: I'd upvote, but I think a few things need fixing. The malloc needs to be casted in c++, org is never initialized, and org will be freed at multiple levels of the recursion.

Comment: @MillieSmith I can see when I try this out that it will be freed multiple times, but I cannot understand how. Can you explain that?

I fixed malloc->new and the initialization.

Comment: I removed the dynamic memory completely now.

Comment: The algorithm is going to recurse multiple times when resta > err. It frees org at each of those since you never set it to nullptr. The change looks good. I'll look at it closer later when i have time.

Comment: I always thought free and delete did set the pointer to null. Well, you learn something everyday. Thanks.

Comment: FreeAndNil does in Delphi :). Yw.

Comment: if you pass 3, it doesnt clear out the static var to null again

Comment: Sorry, to -1 again

Comment: You renamed the function to `r` but you recurse on `raizCuadrada` :). Upvoted regardless. Looks good.

Answer (score 0):

> I basicly want to know how to "save" that first "num" call, somewhere,
>   to use it ALWAYS in the "resta", the "- num" should be always the
>   number that 1st put.
>
> NOTES: I cannot input more inputs. I can only input 1 number and the
>   error. c++

The solution I most often use is to separate the two 'efforts' into two methods:

1) Start with a method (use your original method name) to save the first variable to a safe space.  I will leave the 'where' up to you. Here I have simply made up a new variable name (origNum), in a scope available to the code of each method.  In C++, I would expect that the class containing these methods would 'save' and use an instance data attribute.

```
float  raizCuadrada(float num, float err)  // same name as original
{
    origNum = num;             // "save" original 'num'

    return (raizCuadrada2(num, err));  // continue normally
}
```

2) Then a mild re-factor of your previous code uses the "saved" value.  Since you can not change the parameters, I suggest a slight method name change, here I created raizCuadrada with suffix '2'.

```
float raizCuadrada2(float num, float err) {
   float nuevo = num / 2;
   float resta=(nuevo*nuevo)-origNum;  // use origNum here

   if(resta>err){
      return (raizCuadrada(nuevo, err));
   }
   else if (resta <= err) {
      return (nuevo);
   }
}
```

note - not compiled. not tested.